# Save Image in C# App for retrieval by ASP.NET webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, image

We have a C# app that allows you to effect certain settings for a companion Web application. One of these settings if the logo that should be displayed on the Web Application. To change the logo, using the C# Application, you select a new logo and save it, then the ASP.NET Web App should read the logo and display it on the website. We currently save the user selected logo to the `AppData` folder (Of the computer, not the `App_Data` folder of the ASP.NET Application.)

However, this throws an UnauthorizedAccessException when the ASP.NET Application tries to read back the file. Where can I store this file so as to not have to grant special permissions to the ASP.NET User manually, and that I can save to from a C# application.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why not create a virtual directory in IIS and have the C# application write to that?

Comment: We're not using IIS, we're using UltiDev Cassini Pro (http://ultidev.com/products/UWS-Cassini-Pro/)

Answer (score 0):

Move the AppData folder to a location somewhere inside the root folder of your web site and set it to inherit permissions from parent.